# Can't use RDP with remote desktop user

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

On my laptop, when using RPD, I leave the user field blank, then select the user I want on the remote computer login scree, after the connection is estabilished.

On my desktop, when I leave the field blank, it keeps putting my microsoft email there, and after connection, it doesnt let me choose the users from remote computer, the login screen shows "Another User" with my email on the login/name field. But I need to use the remote computer already existing users.

I've tried changing this line in the connection `authentication level:i:0`
and adding this line `enablecredsspsupport:i:0` as sugested. Nothing changed.

All systems running win10

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft RDP client maintains a cache for the user name and other parameters in the user registry. Every time you start the client it often prefers the cached value...

Check the registry and clear the value `UsernameHint` for your server in the Registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Servers\<your server>\
```

You can modify or delete the `UsernameHint` value.